# setColorFilter does not work in onDrag

Tags: android, colorfilter

In my app I have a textview which I want to put a color filter on its background, when the user drags another item to it. In my DragListener I use the following code But the colorfilter doesn't take effect:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
     v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
```

When I enter the same code in the MainActivity instead of the DragLlistener it works just fine, as follows:

```
findViewById(R.id.textView2).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN)
```

Also in the DragListener When I change the background color to a different color, the colorfilter takes effect and when I change it back to what I want, the colorfilter stays effective. The same goes for clearColorFilter(for it in order to take effect I must change background color).
Here is what I am talking about:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    v.setBackgroundColor(con.getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
```

My question is why do I have to set background color to a different for the colorfilter to take effect in the DragListener, but not in the MainActivity? Am I missing something?

Comment: I researched and found  that ColorDrawable objects tend to ignore colorFilter. this could be the reason for the problem. But the question still stays as why colorFilter works when applied to a ColorDrawable in the MainACtivity and does not work on onDrag function.

Comment: When I use a png Image as background setColorFilter() works just fine but when I use a solid color that's when the problem arises. that's probably because when a solid color is used the getBacground() function returns a ColorDrawable rather than a Drawable (or maybe bitmapDrawable)